# Calling a stored function from oracle DB with cx_Oracle in Python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am not familiar with PL/SQL and just can't transform a working raw query into python code.

Here is the raw query:

```
DECLARE
  returntype MY_PKG_1.MY_DATA_TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
   BULK COLLECT INTO returntype
  FROM TABLE(MY_PKG_2.MY_FUNC(
    param_1 => 'some data',
    param_2 => 'some more data'
  ));
END;
```

It is a valid query that works just fine, I can run it with cursor.execute() with no errors. But how to get the returned rows?
I've tried the following:

```
returntype = connection.gettype('MY_PKG_1.MY_DATA_TYPE')
cursor = connection.cursor()
results = cursor.callfunc('MY_PKG_2.MY_FUNC', returntype, ['some data', 'some more data'])
cursor.commit()
```

But I get an error "ORA-04043: object MY_PKG_1.MY_DATA_TYPE does not exist".

Comment: Your PL/SQL block doesn't return anything to the caller so there are no rows to return.  Is there some reason that you wouldn't just run the `select` statement, sans `bulk collect`, from your Python code?  I don't see what the collection type, local variable, and PL/SQL block are accomplishing.

Answer (score 1):

If the PL/SQL block just does a single query, then execute that query directly without using PL/SQL:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    try:
        for r in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE(MY_PKG_2.MY_FUNC(param_1 => :p1, param_2 => :p2))', p1='some more data', p2='some data')
            print(r)
    except cx_Oracle.Error as e:
        error, = e.args
        print(error.message)
        print(sql)
        if (error.offset):
            print('^'.rjust(error.offset+1, ' '))
```

Otherwise you will have to bind a REF CURSOR, or use Implicit Results.  See the cx_Oracle examples [ref_cursor.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/ref_cursor.py) and [implicit_results.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/implicit_results.py).

If you are returning collections etc, then [this](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/tutorial/solutions/bind_sdo.py#L54-L72) gives some insights into generically traversing them.  But check the doc for simpler examples.

Also see the cx_Oracle doc on [tuning fetch performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).